# jQuery File Upload - Multiple File Upload Widgets on the same page

Tags: jquery, upload

I have the same problem...all thing works fine but during upload but images preview not displaying.

I have looked the wiki page and I found a part of the problem.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page

When the page load, the first request (http://localhost/uploads_icon/server/php/) is not realized when I change the id form (id="fileupload") for a class as it's shown in the wiki.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fileupload').each(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        uploadTemplateId:'template-upload-1',
        downloadTemplateId:'template-download-1'
    });
    $('#fileupload2').fileupload({
        uploadTemplateId:'template-upload-2',
        downloadTemplateId:'template-download-2'
    }); 
});
```

});

When I put the id="fileupload", the get request is perform but I can't have two forms with the same id and only the id="fileupload" allow the images preview displaying.

Anyone could have a trick?

Thanks